# How to deploy AWS Lambda Function Correctly

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

Using serverless, I am trying to deploy a lambda function through AppSync. I see that my function gets deployed in the AWS Console, however, it is showing that it's over 50MB and can't display the inline editing. How do I properly deploy my lambda function?

Here's what the console looks like.

[image]

Comment: You function is deployed, it's just too big to edit in the browser. There's nothing wrong about that.

Comment: Are there any layers? What's in it?

Answer (score 0):

Like @LLL said, the lambda function has already been deployed. One way you can confirm that is by going to your CloudFormation stack and check the status of the lambda function. If it's successfully deployed the status should be `CREATE_COMPLETE` or `UPDATE_COMPLETE`.

If you would like to view the deployed function, you can click the `Actions` dropdown the page you visited in the image and click `Export function`. This will download all the files deployed with your lambda function.